# Scrapy and I'm trying to extract names and links to profiles on a site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I am having and issue extracting the data from a site. I believe I have a logic error because my spider crawls the pages but it doesn't return any scraped data I any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=(r'.*',),
            restrict_xpaths=('//div/div/div/span/a',) #This is the XPath for profiles links that direct to individual pages
        ),
        callback='parse_item',
        follow=True
    ),
      Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=(r'.*',),
            restrict_xpaths=('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " on ")]',) #This is the XPath that cycles through pages
        ),
        callback='parse_item',
        follow=True
    ),
)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('parse_item called for: %s' % response.url, level=log.INFO)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = RealtorSpiderItem()
        item['name'] = hxs.select('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " screenname ")]').extract()
        item['link'] = hxs.select('@href').extract()
        item['city'] = hxs.select('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " locality ")]').extract()

        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

In a crawling spider, you use a rule to find pages from `start_urls` and trigger the `parse_item()` on each match.

I think you wanted to do that:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=('//div/div/div/span/a'), 
            callback='parse_item')
    ),
)
```

So, only one rule to find the links within the `start_urls` pages, and for each match run `parse_item()`.

See [CrawlSpider example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was unable to debug any of my rules because parse_item was not being called due to an indention error.